# oAuth 2.0 service provider for .NET 2.0 web API

Tags: asp.net, .net, api, oauth

We have a classic ASP.NET web application and a SOAP based API built on it. **We are planning to implement oAuth2 authorization into it to implement a service provider that can create tokens, persist them and do evaluation.**

I found few examples using DotNetOpenAuth , Azure access control service but all of them are based on MVC. *Any pointers on how we can implement on oAuth2 on classic ASP.NET web API?*

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few examples of using DotNetOpenAuth with asp.net applications. For instance:
http://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/09/12/integrate-openauth-openid-with-your-existing-asp-net-application-using-universal-providers.aspx

**Edit**
So unfortunately I don't know a direct example with asp.net.
The OAuth1 sample might help in giving the basic idea of how to integrate DotNetOpenAuth as a service provider into an ASP.NET application - 
https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/tree/master/samples/OAuthServiceProvider

And I think that using that as a base, and combining with working with the OAuth2.AuthorizationServer (as the oauth2 samples show, like https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/tree/master/samples/OAuth2ProtectedWebApi), is a good reference point.

Comment: I went through the links above and understand that they are implementations of oAuth 1.0  and not oAuth2.0